# MySQL auto increment does not start at 1

Tags: mysql

My situation is similar to the one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000736/mysql-why-does-my-auto-increment-not-start-at-1-when-doing-inserts). I am trying to insert value to `DogName` and set `DogId` to be `auto_increment` but it does not start at 1

**Dog table**

```
DogId DogName
3     Woofer
4     Kujo
5     Spike
```

I tried the solution in that question

```
alter table <tablename> auto_increment = <some_number>;
```

but did not work. I tried dropping the table and creating it again. But now the `DogId` starts at 6. Really appreciate any help

Comment: how do you insert data, can you post the insert statement

Comment: mysql keeps deleted ids, if you deleted some items it will continue count next id. the only way is reset id then it will contine with the first id like 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried dropping the table and creating it again. But now the DogId
> starts at 6. Really appreciate any help

Try `TRUNCATE` instead.